# excel vba how to reference a macro created worksheet by codename in subsequent running

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new at VBA ad I have the following problem.

I want to reference worksheets by codenames (because the tab name can be modify by the user)
I know that is not possible add a new worksheet specifying the codename.

In a running of my macro I create a new Worksheet using:

```
Worksheets.Add().Name = "aSheet" 
st = Worksheets("aSheet").CodeName
```

now I have the codename in variable st.

In a following run of the macro (in one in which I don't create  the  new worksheets) I want to access the previous created worksheet by codename i.e. I 
want to use code with codename hard coded. I don't want to use

```
st = Worksheets("aSheet").CodeName
```

because  between the two runs of the macro the user must have changed the tab "aSheet" name.

That seems impossible to me, but I hope to be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of going to the workbook's `Worksheets` collection, just refer directly to the worksheet by its codename:

```
debug.print Sheet5.name
```

You can also use it's index if you are super into the Worksheets collection:

```
debug.print Sheets(5).name
```

You might find it helpful to save the worksheet as a global variable (declared outside the scope of your function or subroutine. The global variable will be available after code execution, but will be reset if the workbook is closed and reopened.

```
Dim st As Worksheet

Sub addWorksheet()

    Set st = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add()
    st.Name = "test3"
    Debug.Print st.Name, st.CodeName

End Sub
```

That variable `st` is a worksheet object and can be referenced in any other subroutine or function after it's set.

...later on

```
Sub printWSName()
    Debug.print st.name
End Sub
```

Finally you may want to save this value if the workbook closes. In your Workbook Object in the Project pane you can use the Workbook_BeforeClose and Workbook_Open events to save and recapture this value:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Worksheets("savedStuff").Cells(1, 1).Value = st.Name
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set st = Worksheets(st.Name)
End Sub
```

Comment: I think the point is, OP won't know the codename because they have just created the new sheet

Comment: Haha, you've basically edited my answer into yours so I'll delete mine -- but suggest changing the part where you say `st` is a *workbook* object, rather than *worksheet* object

Comment: JNevill Thank you for your prompt answer, I think it works, tomorrow I'll try.